# Getting coordinates for frequent locations?

Tags: ios, geolocation

In iOS, if “system services” are active in privacy, my “frequent locations” are recorded, but I can only see, for each of them, a fragment of a map and a quite generic description: the name of a road, for instance, which is less than useful for a long, out-of-town road without specific nearby points of reference. Is there a way to get more useful data, such as latitude and longitude?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing directly on the iOS device to provide the coordinates. Through the iOS developer sdk you can access the CLVisit class which has the following properties:

coordinate- which will give you the geographic coordinates
horizontalAccuracy- gives the horizontal accuracy of the above coordinates
arrivalDate- date arrived to location
departureDate- date departed location

There is also a CLFloor class which has the following property

level- which will give you a value for the floor. 0 bring ground floor, 2 being 2 floors above the ground floor, etc.

Comment: Thanks! And is there a way to access these for a non-developer? An app, a computer program?

Comment: I am not aware of any personally but I could probably spin one up.

Comment: I'd be very grateful, but I suppose it's too much to ask...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for something to provide maps, frequently visited places, and perhaps navigation. Have you looked at [Waze](https://www.waze.com)?

It holds favorite and frequent locations, and quite a bit more.

It seems to be the app of choice for navigation these days. (My kids told me that).

It boasts a community of users who let each other know when there is traffic, problems and faster routes.

From their site: "In preparation for major events, or when unforeseen disasters happen, the Waze community updates the map with road closures and other obstructions, so everyone can bypass traffic and save time.".

For planning without the "social aspect", Apple Maps is much better these days, and Google Maps of course, is great.

Here is a shot of some of their settings, to give you an idea:

[image]

Oh, it's free, but has adverts you can pay to remove.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know and use Waze and that's not my request. I look for a way to retrieve locations recorded among the “frequent locations” my iPhone records.